# Unable To Deploy React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, github-pages, netlify

I tried to deploy my django-react app on Github-Pages, Firebase, Netlify.
While deploying on github-pages using gh-pages, i am getting this error

```
sh: 1: gh-pages: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! blog_frontend@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the blog_frontend@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pika/.npm/_logs/2018-08-09T15_30_32_229Z-debug.log
```

And then trying for Firebase.
first I install firebase-tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then i am unable to initialise firebase in the directory. when trying

```
firebase init
```

it says

```
firebase: command not found
```

same case with netlify also.

Here's the log file for error with gh-pages

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: blog_frontend@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pika/Desktop/django/Django-React-Blog/frontend/blog_frontend/node_modules/.bin:/home/pika/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
8 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: /home/pika/Desktop/django/Django-React-Blog/frontend/blog_frontend
9 silly lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: blog_frontend@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pika/Desktop/django/Django-React-Blog/frontend/blog_frontend/node_modules/.bin:/home/pika/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
14 verbose lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: /home/pika/Desktop/django/Django-React-Blog/frontend/blog_frontend
15 silly lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '-c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 info lifecycle blog_frontend@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
17 verbose stack Error: blog_frontend@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
17 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
17 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
17 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
17 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
17 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:5)
18 verbose pkgid blog_frontend@0.1.0
19 verbose cwd /home/pika/Desktop/django/Django-React-Blog/frontend/blog_frontend
20 verbose Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
21 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
22 verbose node v10.8.0
23 verbose npm  v6.2.0
24 error file sh
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno ENOENT
27 error syscall spawn
28 error blog_frontend@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
28 error spawn ENOENT
29 error Failed at the blog_frontend@0.1.0 deploy script.
29 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
30 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: did you try close the terminal and try the command again?

Comment: @I Putu Yoga Permana ... I even restarted my laptop

Comment: 1. There is not enough information. 2. You need to pick one system to deploy to and concentrate. Too many questions in this one question.

Comment: @talves .. I have added the debug log. And I am trying my app to deploy on github pages for a very long time, but still no progress yet

Answer (score 2):

**Check if your `gh-pages` dependency is missing in your package.json file.**

I know this is coming late, but maybe it will help someone in the same fix. I recently had a similar error publishing to Github Pages, and I still don't know how it happened, but somehow my `gh-pages` dependency was no longer installed. I think I might have used it on a discarded branch or something.

Simply running `npm install --save gh-pages` in the terminal restored my app... and my sanity, lol. It's really an annoying little mistake.

I hope this is still relevant to someone in a similar fix.

Comment: This also made me realise I didn't have `gh-pages` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same exact error. I was using Firebase Hosting, but added Firebase Cloud Functions. This modified my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
  }
}
```

I originally setup Cloud Functions with eslint, but decided to remove it later. It appears having that empty `"functions": {}` part was breaking deployments, even when doing `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

Running with `--debug` or just repeatedly trying it (the Firebase tools seem to pickup repeated failures and dumps a log file), revealed the actual cause (at least for me):

```
[2020-05-16T20:26:53.762Z] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:121:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at Object.checkFunctionsSDKVersion [as fn] (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/checkFirebaseSDKVersion.js:33:28)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:159:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Looks like either my json isn't correct for firebase or firebase itself has issues.

I was able to get hosting deployments working again by removing the empty `, "functions": {}` part of my `firebase.json` file.